# Dynamic Listview Builder Navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

Hi I would want to know how to implement a navigation in a listview builder and here is what I have tried.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body:Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    color: AppColors.whiteColor,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[

        Flexible(
          child: AnimationLimiter(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: false,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              itemCount: menuList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                    position: index,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                    child: SlideAnimation(
                      verticalOffset: 44.0,
                      child: FadeInAnimation(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => menuList[index].name(menuList[index].children,widget.name,widget.code)),
                                );


                          },
                          child: Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical*2),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.network(menuList[index].icon),
                              title: Text(menuList[index].name),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ));
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What kind of navigation, what doesn't work in this code?

Comment: Hi @TiagoRossi I would like to navigate to different screens based on the api name:   Eg: menuList[index].name. It should navigate to that page along with parameters.    Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => menuList[index].name(menuList[index].children,widget.name,widget.code)),
                                );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood by your question is that you want to open different activity with respect to different API values on each indices. Why not put an IF condition in your onTap() to check a certain value at each element that indicates where to navigate. For example: 
`if (widget.studentTestInfo.content[index].canSeeResultTr == true) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ResultPageLook(
            studentProfile: widget.studentProfile,
            studentTestInfo: widget.studentTestInfo,
            ), 
          )
       );
    } else {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => TestSyllabus(
              studentProfile: widget.studentProfile,
              studentTestInfo: widget.studentTestInfo,
            ),
          ),
        );
    }`

Comment: Hi @AnshaySIngh this answer would work out for me but can I know what if I have more than 10 routes ? Will this be feasible?

Comment: Using else-if in that situation would work just fine. Although I haven't tried it out myself with more than 4 routes.